# How to load javascript values into python from web page?

Tags: javascript, python-3.x

When I inspect the code on a webpage, I can see the html and the javascript. I've used Beautiful Soup to import and parse the html, but there is a large section written in javascript, which pulls variables from a programmable logic controller (PLC). I can't find the data in python after I load and parse with Beautiful Soup - it's only the html code.

The PLC is being read directly by the webpage and I see the live values updating in front of me, but I can't import them directly. The screen shot is what the code looks like from the inspect window. Let's say I want to import that variable `id="aout7"` with attribute `class="on"`, how can I do that?

[image: Inspect View Source of webpage]

Answer (score 1):

Webpages are best run in a browser. There are API-s for remote controlling a browser/browser engine, a popular one is [Selenium](https://www.seleniumhq.org), and it has Python bindings: see https://pypi.org/project/selenium/ - the page contains instructions for installing:

```
pip install -U selenium
```

and some introductory examples, like this snippet issuing a Yahoo search:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Firefox()

browser.get('http://www.yahoo.com')
assert 'Yahoo' in browser.title

elem = browser.find_element_by_name('p')  # Find the search box
elem.send_keys('seleniumhq' + Keys.RETURN)

browser.quit()
```

You will need something similar, just with `find_element_by_id` (https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html), and use the `text` attribute of elements to read their content.